# Oracle SQL developer. Syntax error while creating storred procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION TODAY(text IN STRING) RETURN STRING AS
DECLARE
    output STRING;
BEGIN
  output := text;
  output += SYSDATE;
  RETURN (output);
END TODAY;
```

The error while compiling is:

> Error(3,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting
>   one of the following:     begin function package pragma procedure
>   subtype type use      form    current cursor external language

Have tried minimize code into:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION TODAY(text IN STRING) RETURN STRING AS
DECLARE
    output STRING;
BEGIN
  RETURN ('a');
END TODAY;
```

And the problem remained, how should I declare variable?

Comment: try putting these 2 lines on same line CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION TODAY(text IN STRING) RETURN STRING AS

Comment: Same problem remains...

Comment: The error says that it was not expecting to see "DECLARE" in the place you put it. Changing code later in the function produces exactly the same error. If you fail to read the error message, think about what it is telling you, and check the syntax you are using against the documentation, then you are not going to have a happy development career.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 problems:

Firstly, you should drop the `DECLARE` keyword.

Secondly, the `STRING` is a `VARCHAR2` really, and you must specify its maximal length, like `STRING(200)`.

Thirdly, to concat values you use the `||` operator. You can't use then `+=` operator, is there is no such operator in PL/SQL. I also recommend using `TO_CHAR` to get the date in the format that you want.

All in all, this works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION TODAY(text IN STRING) RETURN STRING AS
    output STRING(200);
BEGIN
  output := text;
  output := output || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
  RETURN (output);
END TODAY;
/

SELECT today('Today is ') AS val FROM dual;
```

```
VAL
-------------------
Today is 19-11-2013
```

You can read more about date format models in Oracle's Documentation: [Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `DECLARE`. You don't need it in a function declaration.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION TODAY(text IN STRING) RETURN STRING AS
    output STRING;
BEGIN
  output := text;
  output += SYSDATE;
  RETURN (output);
END TODAY;

/
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8696c)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. That works, but have found another problem. strings addition not working, got an error `numeric or value error: character to number conversion error`.

Comment: @user2929533. To concat two values use || instead of +=.

Answer (score 0):

My code:

We do not have to specify 'declare' clause in oracle while declaring variables in function and procedures. We only specify 'declare' if we are making anonymous block.

```
<p>CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION TODAY(text IN STRING) RETURN STRING AS
    output STRING;
BEGIN
  output := text;
  output += SYSDATE;
  RETURN (output);
END TODAY;</p>

enter code here

<p>CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION TODAY(text IN STRING) RETURN STRING AS
    output STRING;
BEGIN
  RETURN ('a');
END TODAY;</p>
```